# Django: object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django

I have to implement several forms, therefore I need the combination of `SingleObjectMixin`, `TemplateView`. I always receive `'AssignAttendee' object has no attribute 'object'`. Do you see why I get that error?

```
class AssignAttendee(SuccessMessageMixin, SingleObjectMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'attendees/front/assign_attendee.html'
    success_message = _("Attendee has been successfully updated.")

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Attendee,
            ticket_reference=self.kwargs['ticket_reference'],
            ticket_code=self.kwargs['ticket_code'],
        )

    @cached_property
    def attendee_form(self):
        return AssignAttendeeForm(
            prefix='attendee',
            data=self.request.POST or None,
            # instance=self.attendee_contact,
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {
            'attendee_form': self.attendee_form,
        }
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: I actually could solve it now. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that it was missing:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```